# Why do packages remain in `package-selected-packages`

Tags: spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs, and I'm adding things to my `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. I can see it is adding tons of packages to `package-selected-packages`.

If I comment out 1 or 2 layers (that I tested and don't want), when I reboot Emacs, I see it's "uninstalling packages," but for some reason they're still listed in `package-selected-packages`.

Why doesn't it auto-remove them from here?

I have so many packages for layers I was experimenting with that I don't want in there.

Comment: Do the packages also stay in `package-selected-packages` if you `M-x package-delete` them?  If not, then maybe it's simply a bug in Spacemacs and you should report it to them?

Comment: Well, I don't use `package-delete` because I never installed the package to begin with, I installed the layer only. So if I add one single layer it might add 20 packages, and when they're all mixed together I have no idea what package goes with what... and theres also way too many of them to attempt to do it one by one (theres hundreds)

Comment: But to answer my question you just have to try it once with one of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put this into your configuration file of **spacemacs**:

```
(defun package--save-selected-packages (&rest opt) nil)
```

I don't know if this works since I don't use **spacemacs**.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, which would prevent `package.el` from adding things to `package-selected-packages` *at all*. e.g. Manually installing a package would no longer add it to the list.

Comment: @phils Yes, it will disable the `package-selected-packages` list, this `list` feature was introduced into Emacs since 25 (25.1??, I don't remember exactly), I was annoyed back then since every time I installed and removed a package (specifically from package manager, but I always delete the package directory to uninstall it), it will change my init.el file automatically (you can move this into another file, but it still gets modified automatically). So I use the above snippet to avoid it, and I don't need the list. Anyway, I don't use Spacemacs, not sure whether this is what the poster wants.